# Remove empty pages between pages

Tags: spacing, floats, formatting, page-breaking, emptypage

I am using this [template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) to write my thesis. I want to remove the empty pages appear between non-empty pages. I don't know how to achieve that. I used google to search for ways to do so but no one works!

Thank you

Comment: `\documentclass[oneside]{MastersDoctoralThesis}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This template seems to be based on the `book` class. Normally two sides pages are assumed and new chapters only start on pages on the right site - this can cause empty pages if the previous chapter also ends on the right site.

To remove these pages use the `oneside` documentclass option.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a way to return the font type to be normal latex font type. The font type used in the template seems weird.

Comment: @Kate Comments are not the best place to ask new questions. If you ask a new question (including a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) , more people will see it and be able to help you.